# General link to get all details of each imdb top 250 movie?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, imdb

for a school assignment I chose to load all of the movies from top250 list dynamically with Ajax to a singlepage and from that page everytime I choose a movie from the list, a popover shows up with the details of that movie. What I wanted to know is how to get a general link for all movies to get the details for each movie on that list because I'm stuck with "The Shawshanks Redemption"-link. Here's the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {



    $.ajax({
        url: "crosscall/crosscall.php",
        data: {
            'url': 'http://www.imdb.com/chart/top?ref_=nv_ch_250_4' //Site van IMDB die de Top 250 toont.
        },
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            var $data = $(data);
            var titel = $('.titleColumn');
            var nummer = 0;
            var imageURL = 'http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BODU4MjU4NjIwNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDU2MjEyMDE@._V1_SX214_AL_.jpg';
            var imageID = 'image';
            var image = $('.posterColumn td a img').attr('src');
            $(document.body).append('<img id="' + imageID + '">');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'hotlink.php?url=' + imageURL,
                success: function (base64data) {
                    $('#' + imageID).attr('src', 'data:image/png;base64,' + base64data);
                }
            });

            $data.find('.titleColumn').each(function () {
                var titel2 = $(this).find('a').text();
                var datum = $(this).find('span[name=rd]').text();
                var plaats = $(this).find('span[name=ir]').text();
                if (titel2.length > 10) titel2 = titel2.substring(0, 38);

                if (nummer < 250) {
                    $('.container').append('<a href="#" class="popLink"><div class="imgurstyle"><div class="titel"><h1>' + plaats + ' ' + titel2 + ' ' + datum + ' </h1></div><img src="' + imageURL + image + '" alt="image"></div></a>');
                }
            });


            //Als men op een film klikt, zal de popover tevoorschijn komen.
            $("a.popLink").click(function (event) {
                //voorkomt dat het link waarop men zal klikken herlaadt.
                event.preventDefault();
                showPopover1();

            });

            var popoverBG;
            var popover;

            //functie popover maken zoals bij de oefeningen die we hadden behandeld tijdens WC.
            function showPopover1() {
                //maak popoverBG
                popoverBG = document.createElement('div');
                popoverBG.className = 'popoverBG';
                document.body.appendChild(popoverBG);
                //maak popover
                popover = document.createElement('div');
                popover.className = 'popover';




                $.ajax({
                    url: "crosscall/crosscall.php",
                    data: {
                        'url': 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/?ref_=chttp_tt_1' //Details van elk filmpagina ophalen.
                    },
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (data) {
                        //gegevens ophalen in popover steken
                        var $data = $(data);
                        var jaartal = $('.infobar');
                        var nummer = 0;

                        $data.find('.infobar').each(function () {
                            var titel = $(this).parent().find('h1 span[itemprop=name]').text();
                            var jaartal2 = $(this).find('.nobr').text();
                            var rating = $(this).find('div .titlePageSprite star-box-giga-star').appendTo('li');
                            console.log($(this).find('.titlePageSprite star-box-giga-star'));
                            var genre = $(this).find('.itemprop').text();
                            var regisseur = $(this).parent().find('div[itemprop="director"] span ').text();
                            var schrijver = $(this).parent().find('div[itemprop="creator"]  span').text();
                            var acteurs = $(this).parent().find('div[itemprop="actors"] span').text();
                            var meerAct = $(this).parent().find('.see-more inline nobr a[itemprop="url"]').text();
                            var plot = $(this).parent().find('p[itemprop="description"]').text();
                            var tijdsduur = $(this).find('time').text();
                            if (nummer < 250) {
                                popover.innerHTML = '<header><h2>' + titel + '</h2></header><ul><li><img src="images/shawshank%20redemption.jpg" alt="n1"></li><li>Release:' + jaartal2 + '</li><li>User ratings:' + rating + '</li><li>Genre: ' + genre + '</li><li>Duur: ' + tijdsduur + '</li><li>Regisseur: ' + regisseur + '</li><li>Schrijvers:' + schrijver + '</li><li>Acteurs: ' + acteurs + ' <a href="#" target="_blank">' + meerAct + '</a></li><li>' + plot + '</li></ul><p>Meer info klik <a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/?ref_=chttp_tt_1" target="_blank">Hier</a><p><a href="#" onclick="removePopover()">Close</a></p>';

                            }

                        });
                    }
                });
                  document.body.appendChild(popover);
                            //voeg click toe aan popoverBG
                            popoverBG.onclick = removePopover;

                            function removePopover() {
                                document.body.removeChild(popoverBG);
                                document.body.removeChild(popover);
                            };
            };
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You've got the link to The Shawshank Redemption hard-coded in your Ajax call `'url': 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/?ref_=chttp_tt_1'` . . . you need to change the reference number (i.e., `tt0111161`) in that URL to point to the different movies.  Are they not returned in your first Ajax call?

Comment: yes they are returned but that is because they're all in one page and easier to request for.

Comment: Well, if they are returned in that first Ajax call, then you should be able to pull out the "tt" values for each of the 250 movies, and generate the correct link to access the details of whichever one that you want.  Not being able to see the data, I'd imagine that you you would call `showPopover1` and pass in that "tt" value, then generate the URL like this: `'url': 'http://www.imdb.com/title/' + MOVIE_ID + '/?ref_=chttp_tt_1'`

Comment: I have a hard time figuring how to work it out. Is there no simple way?

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with the IMDB API's, so I am really going solely on what you've provided.  Perhaps if you gave an example of what the first Ajax returns in your question, it will be easier to come up with specific recommendations.

Comment: Are you actually scraping imdb.com for the top 250 movie titles? Last I read, that was against their AUP. With that said, if you can extract each movie's ID (e.g. tt0111161), you could query omdbapi.